# What's the best practice to update a specific db-table-row-column simultaneously?

Tags: java, database, h2, ebean

A row column in db(**If the row does not exists, it should be created first.**) can be updated by multiple users simultaneously, what's the best practise to update the row efficiently and correctly?

The Model

```
@Entity(table = "counters")
public class Counter {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    /**
     * <b>count</b> and can be updated by users simultaneously and frequently. count is
     * very important, every updates should be success without lost updates.
     */
    public int  count;
}
```

possible solutions:

1) Use synchronized keywords

```
public static synchronized void createOrUpdateCount(int counterId, int increments) {
    Counter counter = Counter.findById(counterId);
    if(counter == null) {
        counter = new Counter();
        counter.count = increments;
    } else {
        counter.count += increments;
    }
    counter.saveToDb();
}
```

2) Use optimistic locking and retry updating if there is a optimistic exception

```
public static createOrUpdateCount(int counterId, int increments) {
    try {
        doCreateOrUpdateCount(counterId, increments);
    } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
        // retry updating on optimistic exception, maybe several times will be 
        // tried until updating succeed.
        doCreateOrUpdateCount(counterId, increments);
    }
}

private static void doCreateOrUpdateCount(int counterId, int increments) {
    Counter counter = Counter.findById(counterId);
    if(counter == null) {
        counter = new Counter();
        counter.count = increments;
    } else {
        counter.count += increments;
    }
    counter.saveToDb();
}
```

3) Set Transation isolation level to Serializable.

```
@Transactional(isolation = TxIsolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public static void createOrUpdateCount(int counterId, int increments) {
    Counter counter = Counter.findById(counterId);
    if(counter == null) {
        counter = new Counter();
        counter.count = increments;
    } else {
        counter.count += increments;
    }
    counter.saveToDb();
}
```

What's your best practise? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to look at the specific database you are using. Most have some type of 'upsert' statement which can perform an insert or update as a single sql statement. You need to then check the database specific documentation regarding that and specifically you are checking to see if you can improve on that by writing a stored procedure to do it (and explicitly choosing to do the most common thing first such as update then insert versus insert then update).

It is very likely that doing this at the ORM level will be no where near as good when compared to using a stored procedure or db specific 'upsert' or 'merge' statement.

Comment: As a Postgres example have a look at the stored procedure called "merge_db" on page:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful, but i hope there are some more discussions on ORM level.

Comment: Sure. In case it is interesting I wrote Ebean ORM and I'm pretty comfortable in saying that something like a 'upsert' or 'counter' will be 1000 times better done in the DB (handling the race condition, network etc). If you choose to still do it in the DB don't use find by id but instead use an update statement and check the executed row count - but seriously ... do this in the DB. That Postgres stored proc is a pretty good indication as to why IMO.